# Split pandas dataframe by rows indices if row indices are recurrent

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a huge CSV file with data from different experiment trials. Whenever the data for a new trial begins, the indices will restart at 0. So my pandas dataframe then would look something like this:

```
     a   b   c
0    ..  ..  ..
1
.
.
n
0
1
.
.
m
0
1
.
.
.
```

Now I want to split the dataframe into smaller dataframes for each trial. So whenever the index restarts at 0 a new dataframe should begin.

Ideally I would like to use list comprehension like this:

```
last_index = [0,n,m,..]  #list of last index for each trial
list_df_trials = [df.iloc[last_index[i]:last_index[i+1]] for i in range(len(last_index-1)]
```

But the problem here is that the indices n,m,.. might appear several times, so I can't guarantee that it will give me the dataframes with the indices [0:n], [0:m],.. like I want. So I might have to do it with a for-loop and remove the already saved rows from the dataframe:

```
list_df_trials = []
last_index = [n,m,..]

for i in last_index:
    df_trial = df.iloc[:i]
    list_df_trials.append(df_trial)
    df = df.iloc[i:]
```

But for both methods actually I don't know how to get the value for all indices before a new 0 index (n,m,..).

I tried to get the indices with `df.index.get_loc(0)` but that only gives me a list with boolean values like this: `[ True False False ... False False False]` in the same shape as the dataframe. So maybe I could return the index of the list with all the True values but I feel like I tried to do this in a complicated way and there could be a much more straightforward way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Example**

minimal example of csv file

```
index,col1,col2
0,a1,a2
1,b1,b2
0,c1,c2
1,d1,d2
2,e1,e2
0,f1,f2
```

make csv file to dataframe

```
import io
text = '''index,col1,col2
0,a1,a2
1,b1,b2
0,c1,c2
1,d1,d2
2,e1,e2
0,f1,f2'''
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(text), index_col=0)
```

`df`

```
        col1    col2
index       
0       a1      a2   
1       b1      b2
0       c1      c2
1       d1      d2
2       e1      e2
0       f1      f2
```

**Code**

I think you want to split the above data frame into lists as follows.

```
        col1    col2
index       
0       a1      a2   
1       b1      b2
                       <--split line
0       c1      c2
1       d1      d2
2       e1      e2
                       <--split line
0       f1      f2
```

Let's split the data frame into groups based on the index starting at 0.

`grp` means grouper

```
grp = (df.index == 0).cumsum()
dfs = [val for key, val in df.groupby(grp)]
```

`dfs`

```
[      col1 col2
 index          
 0       a1   a2
 1       b1   b2,
       col1 col2
 index          
 0       c1   c2
 1       d1   d2
 2       e1   e2,
       col1 col2
 index          
 0       f1   f2]
```